# How do I write a regex with conditional characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How do we apply conditions to blocks in a regular expression?

For example, to write a regex for 6-digit numbers, I would write "([0-9]{6})", 
but say I want to disallow the last two characters from both being 0: that is, one can only be 0 if the other is not.

([0-9]{4})([1-9]{2}) does not fit this case, I would probably have to write conditional statements for [1-9] else [0-9] for the last two characters, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this just to keep it "simple":

`([0-9]{4}(?:[1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9]))`